# Is there layout viewport in android chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

in my `chrome 65.0.3325` on `android 8.10`,

I set css on a element:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

when I start input something in a `input` element, the keyboard popup, the element that positioned by fixed, will also "popup up", seem to position by visual viewport

as I remembered, the `position:fixed`, will position the element by the layout viewport;

why does it failure？

I write a demo to describe the case:
[A Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9oms6grn/7/show)

the screenshot when i run the demo on my phone:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a relevant code snippet. How can we solve it if we can't see what is happening/ wrong

Comment: @SuperDJ: You won't be able to see it anyway, since Stack Snippets doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: @SuperDJ i update the screenshot， thanks